# Issue with polars unique function when using streaming=True

Tags: streaming, unique, lazy-evaluation, python-polars

I am running into an issue when using lazy execution with streaming with the function "unique". Here is an example of code which yields different results for streaming True and streaming False:

```
creation_time = pl.scan_parquet('{}/f42199_stg_00*.parquet'.format(PATH_f42199_FILES))
with open('mappingf42199.json') as json_file:
    mapping = json.load(json_file)
creation_time = creation_time.with_columns(
    [
        julian_to_gregorian('sltrdj').alias('sltrdj')
    ]
).filter(pl.col('sltrdj') >= cutoff_date).with_columns(
    [
        pl.col('sllnid').str.rstrip('0').str.rstrip('.').str.zfill(6).str.slice(0,3).cast(int),
        pl.col('sldoco').cast(float).cast(int),
        pl.col('sltday').str.rstrip('0').str.rstrip('.').str.zfill(6).str.strptime(pl.Time, format='%H%M%S', strict=False),
    ]
).filter(((pl.col('slnxtr') == '519') & (pl.col('slpid') == 'P4210') & (pl.col('sldcto') == 'SZ')) | ((pl.col('slnxtr') == '540') & (pl.col('slpid') == 'EP42101') & (pl.col('sldcto') == 'SO'))).sort('sltday').unique(subset=['sldoco', 'sllnid'], keep='last')

creation_time = creation_time.collect(streaming=True)
```

The issue comes from the part .sort('sltday').unique(subset=['sldoco', 'sllnid'], keep='last'). If I remove that part I get the same results with streaming=True and streaming=False.

If streaming doesn't work properly on this example I would expect polars to throw an error but instead the code runs without errors.

**My question is: am I missing something here? If not I will open a ticket on GitHub to report this issue.**

I verified that streaming=False gives the right result.

Comment: Definitely, create a ticket. We have also recently found out that streaming=True drops rows randomly and is inconsistent with results with streaming=False.